# Block diagonalization of symmetric Toeplitz matrix into m blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a symmetric, real, Toeplitz matrix:

$$
T=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 t_1 & t_2 & \ldots  & \ldots  & t_n \\
 t_2 & t_1 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 \vdots  & \ddots & t_1 & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 \vdots  & \ddots & \ddots & t_1 & t_2 \\
 t_n & \cdots  & \cdots  & t_2 & t_1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Assuming $n$ is divisible by $2$, I can block-diagonalize this into two blocks via a unitary similarity transform off of:

$$
R=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   &   &   &   & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
   & \ddots &   &   & .\cdot{}^{\cdot} &   \\
   &   & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   &   \\
   &   & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   &   \\
   & .\cdot{}^{\cdot} &   &   & \ddots &   \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   &   &   &   & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

here's an example of the symmetrization for the $10x10$ case:

$$
{RTR}^\intercal= \\ \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 t_1+t_{10} & t_2+t_9 & t_3+t_8 & t_4+t_7 & t_5+t_6 &   &   &   &   &   \\
 t_2+t_9 & t_1+t_8 & t_2+t_7 & t_3+t_6 & t_4+t_5 &   &   &   &   &   \\
 t_3+t_8 & t_2+t_7 & t_1+t_6 & t_2+t_5 & t_3+t_4 &   &   &   &   &   \\
 t_4+t_7 & t_3+t_6 & t_2+t_5 & t_1+t_4 & t_2+t_3 &   &   &   &   &   \\
 t_5+t_6 & t_4+t_5 & t_3+t_4 & t_2+t_3 & t_1+t_2 &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   & t_1-t_2 & t_2-t_3 & t_3-t_4 & t_4-t_5 & t_5-t_6 \\
   &   &   &   &   & t_2-t_3 & t_1-t_4 & t_2-t_5 & t_3-t_6 & t_4-t_7 \\
   &   &   &   &   & t_3-t_4 & t_2-t_5 & t_1-t_6 & t_2-t_7 & t_3-t_8 \\
   &   &   &   &   & t_4-t_5 & t_3-t_6 & t_2-t_7 & t_1-t_8 & t_2-t_9 \\
   &   &   &   &   & t_5-t_6 & t_4-t_7 & t_3-t_8 & t_2-t_9 & t_1-t_{10} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We can see we get an additive block and a subtractive block, which in the context this comes from represent a symmetric and anti-symmetric combination of a set of basis functions.

Is there a way to generalize this to $m$ blocks for divisible $n$ and $m$? My intuition suggests it ought to be as the original case derives from effectively a symmetry of order $2$ and there should are symmetries of order $m$ for every $m$, but I don't know where to start in constructing an $R$ for that case.